Jest is unable to recognize Next.js components
I am trying to test a specific component with Jest. However, when I try to render the component using the render function, I get the error: 'Home' is being referenced as a value, but is being used as a type here. Would you like to use 'typeof Home' instead? ts(2749).
Even though I have configured moduleNameMapper in the jest.config.ts file, I am still facing the same issue. I don't know why this is happening. Can you help me?
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "./jest.setup.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

// eslintrc.json

{
  "plugins": ["jsx-a11y", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "jest"],

  "env": {
    // 전역객체를 eslint가 인식하는 구간
    "browser": true, // document나 window 인식되게 함
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest/globals": true,
    "jest": true
  },

  "ignorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/",
    ".eslintrc.js",
    "next.config.js",
    "postcss.config.js",
    "run_server.js",
    "jest.config.ts"
  ]
}

//jest.config.ts
import type { Config } from "jest";
import nextJest from "next/jest.js";

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: "./",
});
const config: Config = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
  },
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,

  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  coverageProvider: "v8",
};

export default createJestConfig(config);

// ./__tests__/Home.test.ts
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Home from "@/app/page";

test("", () => {
  render(<Home />); //error! 'Home' is being referenced as a value, but is being used as a type here. Would you like to use 'typeof Home' instead? ts(2749).
});



This error can happen if you're not using the right extension since your Home component in React should be .jsx or .tsx, did you try to renamed your test file in Home.test.tsx ?

Thank you. I completely forgot that components are only recognized in JSX files. Thanks to you, it is now working properly. It's late, but I really appreciate it.
